Including code inside custom environment
For making homework assignments I define a custom environment (see \soln{} below) to show/hide solutions.  I would like to be able to include code in the solutions somehow, which I ordinarily do with verbatim or the listings package, but I understand that neither work inside other environments. I have read many posts about this but cannot find a solution.  Any suggestions appreciated.
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\soln}[1]{\emph{#1}} % toggle #1/blank to show/hide solutions

\begin{document}

Problem \#1: To include code I use something like
\begin{verbatim}
> pnorm(1.8)
[1] 0.9640697
\end{verbatim}

\soln{Solution: Here's a solution to Problem \#1 where I'd like to include code, but verbatim and listings don't work here.}

\end{document}


Welcome. // Have a look at the versatile listings package: https://ctan.org/pkg/listings . // If you use \newenvironment{yourEnv}{}{} , you can use \begin{yourEnv} and \end{yourEnv}. The two empty braces contain code to execute when entering and leaving this environment, like drawing horizontal rules etc. In between put regular text, which includes a lstlisting environment from said package: just write as needed. Or pass it as parameter, like in your code. // See e.g. here for details: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Macros#New_environments

You may also want to inspect https://ctan.org/pkg/probsoln, which provides some typesetting for problem-solution approaches. // HOWEVER, it will be easier to suggest an appropriate answer (solution) to your question, when you'd add some spelled out example (i.e. printed as text, not as code). Can be from a text editor, a screenshot from Word etc. Anything which show us how you'd like the result to look like. Thanks

Thank you, @MS-SPO, but I don't see how your environment solution would allow me to toggle.

What do you mean by "toggle"? May be this will be more evident, once you add some written output, as I suggested earlier.

@MS-SPO change \newcommand\soln[1]{\emph{#1}} to \newcommand\soln[1]{} and you got the display of the solutions toggled. I guess that's what OP means.

Could be. // Alternatives to that approach: define two newXyz, provide at least one option, use if-cases,  etc.

By "toggle" I mean run it once with \newcommand{\soln}[1]{\emph{}} to generate the assignment, then again with \newcommand{\soln}[1]{\emph{#1}} to generate solutions.

Thank you. // Why not using two macros? Else you‘d need to track and evaluate the number of calls made. // I‘m out now.

Thanks for the suggestion @MS-SPO. Could you say a bit more about what a two macro solution would do?

The following uses enverb (disclaimer: I'm the package author of it), which allows you to collect the contents of an environment verbatimly and then later execute them anywhere you want in the end-code of that environment.
I defined the begin-code of the environment in such a way that you can also continue using it as a normal argument taking macro as you used to in your MWE. But if you use it as an environment you can use verbatim material.
Please note that enverb by default removes two leading spaces from the contents of its environment (this provides nicer syntax in which you can indent the contents), to change this simply change the number to the more-ignore version to your liking, or to disable that use auto-ignore=false (this also disables removing the spaces in front of each line according to its own nesting level) as an option.
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\solnCMD[1]{\emph{#1}} % toggle #1/blank to show/hide solutions

\usepackage{enverb}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\solnName{soln}
\newenvironment{soln}
  {%
    \ifx\@currenvir\solnName
      \expanded{\enverb{more-ignore=2}\expandafter}%
    \else
      \expandafter\solnCMD
    \fi
  }
  {%
    \solnCMD{\enverbExecute}%
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Problem \#1: To include code I use something like
\begin{verbatim}
> pnorm(1.8)
[1] 0.9640697
\end{verbatim}

\soln{Solution: Here's a solution to Problem \#1 where I'd like to include code, but verbatim and listings don't work here.}

\begin{soln}
  Solution: Here's a solution to Problem \#1 where I include code:
  \begin{verbatim}
  > pnorm(1.8)
  [1] 0.9640697
  \end{verbatim}
\end{soln}

\end{document}



Thank you for the tip @Skillmon. But when I run that I get the error
./enverb.sty:39: Undefined control sequence
l.39: \ExpSyntaxOn

@DedekindCuts there's an l missing in \ExplSyntaxOn.

@DedekindCuts how did you install enverb? Did you (perhaps accidentally) alter it? I just checked and in my TeX Live installation there is no typo in that line.

Sorry that was my own typo here (can't copy/paste my TexShop console).  It should be l.39 \ExplSyntaxOn  I didn't alter anything.

You're most likely using a rather old version of LaTeX (pre 2020). Either update your system or (if that's not an option) put \usepackage{expl3} into your preamble before \usepackage{enverb} and hope that this will work out. If it doesn't I'm sorry, but I don't actively support old TeX Live versions (but from a quick look the used expl3 functions should be available since 2015).

@DedekindCuts forgot the ping, so here it is for my previous comment :)

Thanks for the suggestion, but including \usepackage{expl3} gives me other errors

@DedekindCuts in that case you should really update your LaTeX installation.

Let me remind you from my comments that this package probably provides all and more than you want.
With the route taken below you can comment out solutions you don't want to show, use some package for conditional compile etc.
Your problem description is rather thin to my taste. So I assumed you're trying to put some notes from day to day: a lessons diary or so. How to arrive here?

1. \newcommand vs. \newenvironment
The \newcommand doesn't coexist with calls to other environments inside, while the \newenvironment ... does. So you could define as a prbl-environment:

taking 1 parameter (#1, the problems "number")
specifying what to typeset before entering this environment
and what when leaving
to use it just write \begin{prbl} ...anyText ... \end{prbl}

\newenvironment{prbl}[1]%                   parameter 1: number
    {\parindent0pt\textbf{Problem #1:\\}}%  before entering environment
    {\rule{3cm}{1pt}}%                      when leaving this environment

The sltn environment is just a copy with some minor adjustments. Change typesetting to both (before/after parts) as you want it to print later.
2. Your content ...
... could look like this for a first problem, where I used both a listing- and a verbatim environment inside as a demo:
% ~~~ One problem ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 
\begin{prbl}{123}
 Here you describe your problem, put some code etc.
 
    \begin{lstlisting}[title={A call to R}]
> pnorm(1.8)
[1] 0.9640697
    \end{lstlisting}
    
    \begin{verbatim}
Let's say it verbatim
or so   \end{verbatim}
\end{prbl}

3. The preamble
... just provides what's needed for the listing and the content of a solution 3B.7 shown:
% ~~~ for code listings ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=R, numbers=left}   % format as R-code
% ~~~ for a demo ~~~~~~~~~~~
\usepackage{tikz}


Readers can reuse the typo ;-)
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
% ~~~ for code listings ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=R, numbers=left}   % format as R-code
% ~~~ for a demo ~~~~~~~~~~~
\usepackage{tikz}

% ~~~ own environments ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\newenvironment{prbl}[1]%                   parameter 1: number
    {\parindent0pt\textbf{Problem #1:\\}}%  before entering environment
    {\rule{3cm}{1pt}}%                      when leaving this environment

\newenvironment{sltn}[1]%                   parameter 1: number
    {\parindent0pt\textbf{Solution to #1:\\}}%  before entering environment
    {\hfill\rule{5cm}{1pt}\hfill}%          when leaving this environment

% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\begin{document}

This here is from the first lesson. We had a full lass room, but the topic was interesing. At least for me.\bigskip

% ~~~ One problem ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 
\begin{prbl}{123}
 Here you describe your problem, put some code etc.
 
    \begin{lstlisting}[title={A call to R}]
> pnorm(1.8)
[1] 0.9640697
    \end{lstlisting}
    
    \begin{verbatim}
Let's say it verbatim
or so   \end{verbatim}
\end{prbl}

\section{The other day}
Now things got tougher. Hey, after all, we are not here for fun \dots That's what they keep telling me \dots

% ~~~ Next problem ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 
\bigskip
\begin{prbl}{3B.7}
 Show me some Tikz code.
 
\end{prbl}

% ~~~ its solution ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\bigskip
\begin{sltn}{3B.7}

    \tikz{\node[draw=teal] at (0,0) {hello world!};
          \node[draw=red,rotate=-20] at (1,1) {waving};}

    \begin{lstlisting}[title={Copied Tikz code}]
\tikz{\node[draw=teal] at (0,0) {hello world!};
      \node[draw=red,rotate=-20] at (1,1) {waving};}

    \end{lstlisting}

\end{sltn}
\end{document}

